# Good practice when defining a PHP class

Tags: php, oop

I've seen some PHP class definitions that include lots of methods that seem unrelated (or at best loosely related) to the actual class. For example:

```
class Dog {
    public $var;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function eat() {
        // Code here is relevant to dog.
    }

    public function sleep() {
        // Code here is relevant to dog.
    }

    public function play() {
        // Code here is relevant to dog.
    }

    public function pay_milkman() {
        // The code here isn't really related to the life of a dog but is useful in the rest of the project.
    }

    public function go_to_work() {
        // The code here isn't really related to the life of a dog but is useful in the rest of the project.
    }

    etc...
}
```

Is it good practice to have a single class do *everything* or should I be writing code that is more modular?

I'd be grateful if you could explain *why* in any answers you might kindly provide.

Comment: Write more modular code. The reasons are too numerous to articulate in an answer here. Just do it.

Comment: Your question is terrible, read about OOP, because as we can see, you don't understand it. Your example code is totally meaningless in this case.

Comment: @kmlnvm my example isn't how I would do it. As I mentioned in my question, I keep seeing huge monolithic class definitions and that's made me question my own modular approach. Hence, why I asked the question.

Comment: @kmlnvm: it would be helpful when you critique questions to say more about why you think it is off-topic and maybe use less language that might be interpreted as rude (for the avoidance of doubt, "your question is terrible" and "your example is meaningless" could be reasonably interpreted as hostile). If the OP appears not to understand something, surely that is the purpose of asking a question? (This question _might_ be too broad for here, but I think I will refrain from voting to close, as it is edge-case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your class just needs some specialised cases:

```
class Dog {
    public $var;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function eat() {
        // Code here is relevant to dog.
    }

    public function sleep() {
        // Code here is relevant to dog.
    }

    public function play() {
        // Code here is relevant to dog.
    }
}

class ExtremelySmartAndWellTrainedDog extends Dog {
    public function pay_milkman() {
        // Code here is relevant to a well-trained dog
    }
}

class SheepDog extends Dog {
    public function go_to_work() {
        // Code here is what sheepdogs do
    }
}
```

Of course, if it is possible to have a dog that is both smart/well-trained *and* working, then I would implement those methods in traits instead.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I think extending a class makes sense in the case of `ExtremelySmartAndWellTrainedDog` and `SheepDog`. You're right in that the code is relevant to what sheep dogs (and extremely well trained dogs) do. But perhaps I can bring in an example of a real-world situation. In the WordPress Plugin Directory, there are many many plugins that include methods such as `load_textdomain()` and `enqueue_styles()` all in the same class definition. These methods aren't directly relevant to the class and (in my opinion) would be better coded as stand-alone functions.

Comment: I think it is down to subjective views as to what belongs with what, @henrywright. I'm only slightly familiar with WP, but since plugins need to render styles, I can see why `enqueue_styles()` might be related to a plugins class. Would it be better as a plugins-styles class? Possibly, I don't really have a view. I certainly take your point in general though - unrelated things should not appear in the same class.

Comment: Thanks @halfer, I appreciate the time you've taken to discuss these points, It's been helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Dogs do not pay milkmen nor do they (usually) work, so those functions should not be in the Dog class. Those functions would go in a class like `Person`, who might own one or more dogs via a relationship between the two classes, i.e.:

```
class Person {
  public $dogs;
  public function buy_dog() {
    $dog = new Dog;
    $this->dogs[] = $dog;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your asking if using lots of function within a class is a bad approach. In my opinion it really depends. When developing Object Oriented applications I always think of all possible functions / methods that I could use for that class.

There is even more. For example there are birds that fly and others that don't so my approach to Object Oriented would be the following.

```
class Bird
{
   public $canfly;

   public function __construct($canfly)
   {
       $this->canfly = $canfly;
   }

   public function canFly()
   {
       return $this->canfly;
   }
}
```

A Penguin is a bird but doesn't fly.

```
class Penguin extends Bird
{
   public function canFly()
   {
      // return parent::canFly(); <- Original Property from parent.
      return false; // Override
   }
}
```

Test the classes

```
$class = new Penguin(false);
if($class->canFly() == false)
{
   print("Bird can't Flye");
}
```

There are many examples out there. Click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipp4WPDwwvk&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF0RicJb20da8nECQ1jFvla) for a really good tutorials.

Comment: Yeah, sorry been programming in Java all month will edit it now.

Comment: Also, the `Penguin` doesn't seem to have overridden anything. I thought you might override `canFly` and return `false`, perhaps?

Comment: This example was simply to demonstrate inheritance how a class of the same type can inherit its parents properties etc. I'll edit my question again to make it more understandable.

Comment: Sure, I was just adding another idea `:-)`.